# Filter called only for servlets

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

How can i use a Filter just for servlets and not for jsp?

```
url-patterns :

/* - this makes the container to call the filter for servlets as well as jsp.
*.jsp - this makes the container to call the filter only for jsp.
```

Is there any way it calls the filter only for servlets..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since filter is mapped to URL and the mapping is always "positive", i.e. you cannot say "call this filter unless url is *.jsp) the only solution is create special URLs for either servlets or JSPs.

For example you can map all your servlets to URLs that end with `*.do`, e.g. `create.do`, `delete.do` etc.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Create Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/create.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Delete Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/delete.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you can create filter and map it to `*.do`:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>actionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It will work for all servlets (because they are mapped to `*.do`) and will not work for JSPs (because they are *not* mapped to `*.do`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a Dummy Filter that doesn't propagate to the FilterChain, i.e. not calling FilterChain.doFilter() in the Dummy Filter, but including the requestdispatcher for jsp files.

```
public class NOPDummyFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getServletContext().getContextPath()
            .substring(req.getServletContext().getC‌​ontextPath().lastIndexOf('/') + 1)).include(request, response);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

and in the web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>NOPDummyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>NOPDummyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>NOPDummyFilter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>MyRealServletFilter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

see this discussion: http://www.coderanch.com/t/169859/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/Filter-has-Exclude-url-pattern

hope this helped.

Comment: but if i dont call chain.doFilter(), it wont call the jsp which in my case is the welcome file. So it displays a blank page.

Comment: you should be able to do something like: `req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/header.jsp").include(request, response);` in the doFilter() method to have the filter forward or include a RequestDispatcher for the JSPs. But i'm not a 100 percent sure about that.

Comment: well of course you will have to parse the jsp name from the request.

Comment: i worked with AlexR's method .. but i would like to know how do i parse it using request?

Comment: you can get the jsp name with `req.getServletContext().getContextPath().substring(req.getServletContext().getContextPath().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);`

Comment: thnx a lot.. i also found an alternative. req.getHeader("referer");

Answer (score 0):

[image]

And code:

```
    // Check if request goto a Servlet
private boolean needFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //
    // Servlet Url-pattern: /path/*
    //
    // => /path
    String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
    // => /abc/mnp
    String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();

    String urlPattern = servletPath;

    if (pathInfo != null) {
        // => /path/*
        urlPattern = servletPath + "/*";
    }

    // Key: servletName.
    // Value: ServletRegistration
    Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> servletRegistrations = request.getServletContext()
            .getServletRegistrations();

    // collection of all servlets in your webapp.
        // containing *.jsp & *.jspx   
    Collection<? extends ServletRegistration> values = servletRegistrations.values();
    for (ServletRegistration sr : values) {
        Collection<String> mappings = sr.getMappings();
        if (mappings.contains(urlPattern)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```